# Чи є український відповідник до слова "кейтеринг"?

Tags: терміни, іменники, запозичені-слова

У [відділі проектів УКУ](https://guests.ucu.edu.ua/kejteryng/) є розділ **"кейтеринг"**. Так, у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) читаю визначення цього недавно прибулого терміну:

> ***Кейтеринг*** (англ. catering від cater — «поставляти провізію») — галузь громадського харчування, пов'язана з наданням послуг на віддалених точках, що включає всі підприємства і служби, що надають підрядні послуги з організації харчування співробітників компаній і приватних осіб у приміщенні і на виїзному обслуговуванні, а також здійснюють обслуговування заходів різного призначення і роздрібний продаж готової кулінарної продукції. На практиці під кейтерингом мається на увазі не тільки приготування їжі і доставка, а й обслуговування персоналом, сервірування, оформлення столу, розлив і подача напоїв гостям і тому подібні послуги.

Однак цікавить, чи є відповідник до цього слова? Як можна заміни термін українським словом або словосполучення?

Comment: добре, зараз виправлю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/keiteryng) пропонують такі варіанти:

> виїзне кафе
>
> мобільна кухня

Comment: Нагадаю, що _кафе_, _мобільний_ та _кухня_ не зовсїм питомі українські слова.